# UWP Modal Window

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I want to show a modal window on the screen in my Universal Windows Platform app (C#), just like the standard Mail-app does when you add an account. Or when you're signing in to a service (like facebook) in an app.

*Windows mail app with modal window:*
[image: Windows 10 mail app - Add account screen]

You can move this window around, but it's not in the taskbar and it is modal.

Does anyone know how to do this? It shouldn't be so hard but i can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Daniel Meixner said, adding account interaction of this Mail app is calling another app possible with [LaunchForResults](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269386.aspx).

Using `Task Manager` of system, you can see that, when you launch this Mail app, it starts a process with the app's name "Mail", and when you add an account from this app, it starts another process with the app's name "Email and accounts".

[image]

If we use the [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to check on these processes, the Mail app's process is this:
[image]

and the add account process is this:
[image]

They are in different processes and have different package names.

So I created two apps and use `LaunchForResult` for communication between these apps, they act just like the Mail app of system.
[image]

If you just want to launch the system's "add account" app, you can refer to the official [UserDataAccountManager sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserDataAccountManager).

Answer (score 4):

In the mail app what's happening might be app to app communication with "LaunchForResults" - I'm not sure, but it looks like that.

With Windows 10 Universal Apps you can make one app call another app with LaunchForResults. The called app will always behave like a modal dialog to the calling app.
You can pass any serializable objects in both directions using ValueSets.

Details for LaunchForResult can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt269386.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a movable window, but you can't make it modal.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f1328991-b5e5-48e1-b4ff-536a0013ef9f/is-it-possible-to-open-a-new-window-in-uwp-apps?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: But why is it possible in the mail-app then?

Comment: Because it is not a window, it is another app.