# make a content Dialog movable like the one in the Groove app

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have created a ContentDialog to apply a Style (that I can't apply with a Message Dialog and a PopUp),but I am having problem with it,it's not movable or I can't close it like the Frame that appears when I click on the button "Connexion"in the Groove App
[image]

have you please any idea,which part I can modify in [the ContentDialog style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx) to get this ContentDialog movable and close it like the image  on top

I work on a universal app

Answer (score 7):

> have you please any idea,which part I can modify in the ContentDialog style to get this ContentDialog movable and close it like the image on top.

I'm afraid `ContentDialog` is not movable, and the image you showed in the Groove App or in the System's mail app is not a `ContentDialog`, actually, this “Dialog” is called by [UserDataAccountManager.ShowAddAccountAsync](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/UserDataAccountManager/cs/Scenario1_AddAccount.xaml.cs). If we used the ProcessMonitor to track this UI, we will find that this is a system app C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.AccountsControl_cw5n1h2txyewy. You may  see the pictures and information in the similar question on SO: [UWP Modal Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756432/uwp-modal-window/34782282#34782282).

For you problem, we can’t launch the system app like Microsoft.AccountsControl for result, we can only call it using API `UserDataAccountManager.ShowAddAccountAsync`. But you can create a UWP app, and launch this app for result from another app, to do this, please refer to [Launch an app for results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results).

Or if you just want a movable UI, you can create a new window in your app, and change the size of this new window, make it popping behavior like a `ContentDialog`, but this new window will show your app's title which can't be removed.

How to create a new window? For example:

```
    private async void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newCoreAppView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        await newCoreAppView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Low, async () =>
        {
            var window = Window.Current;
            var newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

            var frame = new Frame();
            window.Content = frame;

            frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage));            
            window.Activate();
            await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newAppView.Id, ViewSizePreference.Default, appView.Id, ViewSizePreference.Default);

        });
    }
```

And how to change the size of the new Window? For example in the cs file of the page showed in the new window:

```
public BlankPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Page_Loaded;
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
            s.TryResizeView(new Size { Width = 600, Height = 320 });
        }
```

This will make a 600 width and 320 height window.

Comment: I have tried the example in your link,but I get an exception  "The specified module could not be found" here " String userDataAccountId = await UserDataAccountManager.ShowAddAccountAsync(UserDataAccountContentKinds.Email | UserDataAccountContentKinds.Appointment | UserDataAccountContentKinds.Contact);"

Comment: @user3821206 I assume that you didn't add "using Windows.ApplicationModel.UserDataAccounts;" and "using Windows.ApplicationModel.Email" in your code, you can just click the wrong tip and choose the suggestion information to add.

Comment: @user3821206, if you don't know how to implement this api, you can download the official [UserDataAccountManager sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserDataAccountManager).

Comment: sorry,I have downloaded the sample and I still get it work,is there any informations I will put in this code?I have checked "all the App capability declarations" like the description said :(

Comment: Yeah, there is a little problem in the sample, you can remove the **Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP** extension from the project's **References**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106071/discussion-between-grace-feng-msft-and-user3821206).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it the other way:

1. Create a UserControl, define the UI like the pop up.
2. Set ManipulationMode to Translate.
3. Handle ManipulationDelta event to move
4. the UserControll (lets put a CompositeTransform as RenderTransform).
5. Implement animation as you want Use the UserControll in your Page

Answer (score 1):

This is How I did it as I didn't found any answers from 4 years till now :)

```
                            var dialog = new ContentDialog()
                            {
                                Title = "This is a Title!",
                                ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.All,
                            };
                            dialog.ManipulationDelta += delegate (object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
                            {
                                if(!e.IsInertial)
                                    dialog.Margin = new Thickness(
                                        dialog.Margin.Left + e.Delta.Translation.X,
                                        dialog.Margin.Top + e.Delta.Translation.Y,
                                        dialog.Margin.Left - e.Delta.Translation.X,
                                        dialog.Margin.Top - e.Delta.Translation.Y
                                        );
                            };
```