# how to make a ContentDialog movable in a universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have created a ContentDialog to apply a Style (that I can't apply with a Message Dialog),but I am having problem with it,it's not movable

so is it possible to make this ContentDialog movable,I have tried to set the `ManipulationMode="Rotate"` and I have implement the `ManipulationDelta="Localisation_ManipulationDelta"` like this:

**MyContentDialog.xaml.cs:**

```
 private void Localisation_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var ct = (ContentDialog)sender;
            var currentProjection = ct.Projection as PlaneProjection ?? new PlaneProjection();
            ct.Projection = new PlaneProjection() { GlobalOffsetX = currentProjection.GlobalOffsetX + e.Delta.Translation.X, GlobalOffsetY = currentProjection.GlobalOffsetY + e.Delta.Translation.Y };
        }
```

but it does not work,the ContentDialog doesn't move :(

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I think that ContentDialog isn't movable, so if you are using ContentDialog as Modal Window in UWP you can [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929032/make-a-content-dialog-movable-like-the-one-in-the-groove-app).

I hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,actually,I have seen this Post,and I think that the second option is the closest to my case and I have try the code,but always  this ContentDialog doesn't move :(

Comment: I use the **Grace Feng - MSFT** approach  and it works, the other answer I think that it is invalid.