# How use ContextFlyout in a StackPanel in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

In a GridView, I am trying to show a context menu when the user right clicks an item.

I tried:

```
 <GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="120" Background="LightBlue">
       <StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
             <MenuFlyout>
                  <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change color" Click="ChangeColorItem_Click" />
             </MenuFlyout>
...
```

But `StackPanel.ContextFlyout` throws an error. What I am missing?

**UPDATE**

The error is: `The attachable property 'ContextFlyout' was not found in type 'StackPanel'`

ContextFlyout is a property of UIElement, and StackPanel is derived from  UIElement.

Comment: Which error? Do you have some message from it? Post it, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ContextFlyout is a property of UIElement, and StackPanel is derived from UIElement.

Yes you are right, but be careful that this `ContextFlyout` property is available since the introduced version 3.0, version 10.0.14393.0. What you need is to check your API contract version and device family version.

For API contract version 1.0/2.0, as @Igor Damiani suggested, you can use `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout`, and you can get the `DataContext` for example in the `RightTapped` event of the `StackPanel`:

```
private void StackPanel_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(sender as StackPanel);
    var datacontext = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext;
}
```

But I noticed that your `MenuFlyoutItem` is possible for color changing, what you need is actually access to the UIElements inside the `StackPanel` or this `StackPanel` itself. If so, it's better to bind the color to a property which is implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: When using this inside a UserControl and adding a MenuFlyoutSubItem, the submenu seems to get cut off when it goes outside the window

Comment: @Arlo, AFAIK, it's by design that all UI elements should be contains inside the frame in UWP app, if you want to show dialog in another window, you may refer to my answer in this question: [make a content Dialog movable like the one in the Groove app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929032/make-a-content-dialog-movable-like-the-one-in-the-groove-app/35934870#35934870).

Comment: Actually I was able to solve it by making the context menu show under the pointer instead of at the element

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="120" Background="LightBlue">
         <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change color" Click="ChangeColorItem_Click" />
            </MenuFlyout>
         </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
```

You need to manually manage the MenuFlyout with a little code-behind.

Comment: Despite being unintuitive, this is the correct syntax