# disable any click on elements from the MainPage when a PopUp is launched

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to display a PopUp in my C# universal app like this :

[image]
but the problem,is that my PopUp deosn't work like this Frame that appears in the Groove App,per example,what I want is when I click on a button in the MainPage, it displays the PopUp then to disable the click on any element in the MainPage,the focus will be only on the elements of the Popup until the close of this PopUp
is this possible??
thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP Modal Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756432/uwp-modal-window)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a modal window, for example you can create one with [Content dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx).

```
 ContentDialog modalWindow = new ContentDialog()
 {
   Title = "youTitle",
   Content = "Content",
   PrimaryButtonText = "
 };
 await modalWindow.ShowAsync();
```

You can show more [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f1328991-b5e5-48e1-b4ff-536a0013ef9f/uwpis-it-possible-to-open-a-new-window-in-uwp-apps?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,I have already used a ContentDialog,it allows may to disable the Parent when it launches but it can be movable :(

Comment: If you want it you can use the Jay Zuo answer, They use two apps, one main, and the other that seems a PopUp window.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "PopUp" you've seen in the Groove App is not a [`Popup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842). It's a [`AccountsSettingsPane`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.applicationsettings.accountssettingspane.aspx). This class provides methods to show the accounts pane and also to enable the app to register callbacks when the accounts flyout is about to be displayed. For more information, please refer to the official [Web account management sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement) in GitHub and especially the Single Microsoft Account scenario in this sample.

When using `AccountsSettingsPane`, if we use the [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to track this UI, we will find that it is a system app `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.AccountsControl_cw5n1h2txyewy`. What happened here is similar to this case: [UWP Modal Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756432/uwp-modal-window/34769627). So you can refer to [Launch an app for results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results) to implement this behavior. But this requires you to create another app.

For `ContentDialog`, it can not be movable. If your content is not complex, you can try with [`MessageDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) class. This dialog is movable. For more info, please refer to [Message dialog sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MessageDialog).