# uwp How To Show a LoginWindow and lock the MainWindow

Tags: c#, uwp

Hello.
                      How do I display a LoginForm in UWP and lock MainWindow when displayed?. Just like showdialog () in WPF.
The following code shows a new form coming out

I Need a modal window

```
     static bool viewShown = false;`enter code here`
                static bool viewClosed = false;
                static int newViewId;
                static int currentViewId;
                static Frame frame;

            private async void btnUserLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
                if (viewShown)
                {
                    if (viewClosed)
                    {
                        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
                        viewClosed = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(newViewId);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        var newWindow = Window.Current;
                        var newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
                        newAppView.Consolidated += NewAppView_Consolidated;
                        newAppView.Title = "登录";
                        ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = newAppView.TitleBar;

                        // Title bar setting                    
                        //......

                        frame = new Frame();
                        frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
                        newWindow.Content = frame;
                        newWindow.Activate();

                        newViewId = newAppView.Id;
                    });
                    viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
                }

            }
```

But this did not lock the main interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP Modal Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756432/uwp-modal-window)

Comment: Can you use contentDialog? See:[win10 UWP MessageDialog 和 ContentDialog](http://lindexi.oschina.io/lindexi//post/win10-UWP-MessageDialog-%E5%92%8C-ContentDialog/)